# Custom Loss function in TensorFlow with step losses

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I wrote a custom loss function that penalizes most for the wrong sign of the prediction, square error for large and abs of loss for small differences:

```py
class CustomLoss(keras.losses.Loss):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        error = y_true - y_pred
        wrong_direction = y_true * y_pred < 0
        small_diff = tf.abs(error) < 0.005

        large_loss = 10 * tf.square(error)
        square_loss = tf.square(error)
        linear_loss = tf.abs(error)

        return tf.where(wrong_direction, large_loss, tf.where(small_diff, linear_loss, square_loss))

    def get_config(self):
        base_config = super().get_config()
        return {**base_config}
```

This works fine, but the training is very slow. I thought it may be because I didn't use tf.cond(), so tried to implement it this way, but it doesn't work:

```py
linear_loss = tf.cond(tf.abs(error) < 0.005, tf.abs(error), tf.square(error))

return tf.where(wrong_direction, large_loss, linear_loss)
```

Any idea how to implement it correctly or is it going to affect training time?

Comment: What do you mean by slow? Also could you check if `tf.abs` isn't causing any problems during training? As far as I can tell, since `abs` is non-differentiable at 0, it might cause some issues. Need to check

Comment: So for I didn't have any problem with that, I'm using 'relu' and 'swish' as activation fucntions. By slow I mean it's clearly slower compared to using MSE or MAE

Comment: The number of total operations in your custom loss function is higher than simple MSE or MAE. But can you quantify "slowness"? I don't think there should be any noticeable difference at all

Comment: So you think it wouldn't help to convert python functions to tf functions?

Comment: Your loss function is not continuous and has ill defined gradient at ypred near 0 for non zero ytrue, which may spoil the network weights during backward propagation. I dont see any reason to slow training except that.